# OpenAcc for Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, openacc

Using Visual Studio I am able to build and execute C++ code that uses CUDA on my workstation equipped with a geforce gtx 560 ti GPU.  I have also downloaded the OpenACC toolkit from NVIDIA Developer website, and I want to install it for my Windows OS. However, I keep reading that I need a linux based OS to install, but that the PGI compiler is supported by Windows. Is it possible to install the OpenAcc for Windows and build/execute in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

PGI supports C and Fortran on Windows, Linux and MacOSX.  C++ is available on Linux.  The Portland Visual Fortran (PVF) product is a VS plugin. The C compiler is available via the command line.  OpenACC is supported in both C and Fortran on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just installing Ubuntu on my workstation. I am able to use the PGI compiler just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it with Visual Studio, but I have downloaded the PGI compiler for Windows and built an OpenACC code using their trial license. They sell a product called PGI Visual Fortran which *does* integrate with VS, so I would expect that you can do the same with the C and C++ compilers.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just installing Ubuntu on my workstation. I am able to use the PGI compiler just fine now.

Comment: Have you tried C++11 or just C sample? The original question was asking about C++.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I just checked my install and I have the C compiler but not the C++ compiler. On the PGI website I see: `Note: Effective with the PGI 2016 release, the PGI C++ compiler is no longer supported on Microsoft Windows.`